# Gitlab self-managed static page not loaded

Tags: gitlab

I faced one issue when I tried to change my default port number for gitlab self-managed version. The screenshot below shows that the static files is not loaded when I changed the port number to 8080, default is 80. Someone please help me with this issue!!! Much appreciated!!!

*Ubuntu server 20.04.3 LTS on Dell Precision Tower 3640.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an Omnibus installation, it depends on how you did mody the default port.

It should be by [Setting the NGINX listen port](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#setting-the-nginx-listen-port)

```
nginx['listen_port'] = 8080
```

And you are supposed to run (possibly as root)

```sh
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
gitlab-ctl restart
```

Make sure, [as in here](https://serverfault.com/a/1050557/783), your `external_url` remain with HTTP.